# Reducing JavaScript weight for repetitive function

Tags: javascript

I'm not exactly a JS pro, and while not pretty or efficient, this works.

Effectively I have repeating field groups in the form, and allow the user to copy data from the first to all 5 if they want to.

How do I make this code more efficient?

```
function data_copy() {
if(document.pixelform.copy[0].checked){

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval2.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval2.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval2.value=document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval3.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval3.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval3.value=document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval4.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval4.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval4.value=document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval5.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval5.value=document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval5.value=document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;

} else {

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval2.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval2.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval2.value="";

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval3.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval3.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval3.value="";

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval4.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval4.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval4.value="";

document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval5.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval5.value="";
document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval5.value="";

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
{
  document.pixelform["pixelpostclickinterval" + i].value=document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
  document.pixelform["pixelpostviewinterval" + i].value=document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
  document.pixelform["pixelsegmentinterval" + i].value=document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;
}
```

Comment: While this piece of code is definitely more compact, this still queries the DOM for the same elements over and over again, every time the `data_copy` function is called. So, performance-wise, this is not as efficient as it looks.

Comment: It clearly isn't. But with the op being a newbie I tried to provide a solution that is simple. And from the look of it, this isn't a place that is worth optimizing for performance ("premature optimization is the root of all evil").

Answer (score 1):

What you have is most efficient in terms of performance, but for maintainability, this is preferred. JavaScript objects are dictionaries and as such, properties may be accessed using index key names.

```
var postclickinterval = "";
var postviewinterval = "";
var segmentinterval = "";

if (document.pixelform.copy[0].checked)
{
    postclickinterval = document.pixelform.pixelpostclickinterval1.value;
    postviewinterval = document.pixelform.pixelpostviewinterval1.value;
    segmentinterval = document.pixelform.pixelsegmentinterval1.value;
}


for (var i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
{
    document.pixelform["pixelpostclickinterval" + i].value = postclickinterval;
    document.pixelform["pixelpostviewinterval" + i].value = postviewinterval;
    document.pixelform["pixelsegmentinterval" + i].value = segmentinterval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop and array.

```
 var pixelInfo = ['postview','postscript','segment'];
 function copydata() {
       if (document.pixelform.copy[0].checked){
           for (var i=2; i<6; i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
                (function(idx,info){
                     document.pixelform['pixel'+pixelInfo[info]+idx].value =
                         document.pixelform['pixel'+pixelInfo[info]+'1'].value;
                 })(i,j);
              }
            }
         } else {
            for (var i=2; i<6; i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
                    (function(idx,info){
                         document.pixelform['pixel'+pixelInfo[info]+idx].value = "";
                 })(i,j);
              }
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to cache a reference to `document.pixelform` to avoid querying the DOM for the same elements over and over again, and to avoid excessive property lookups.

```
// Look up the elements only once
var pf = document.pixelform,
    pci2 = pf.pixelpostclickinterval2,
    pci3 = pf.pixelpostclickinterval3,
    pci4 = pf.pixelpostclickinterval4,
    pci5 = pf.pixelpostclickinterval5,
    pvi2 = pf.pixelpostviewinterval2,
    pvi2 = pf.pixelpostviewinterval2,
    pvi2 = pf.pixelpostviewinterval2,
    pvi2 = pf.pixelpostviewinterval2,
    pvi2 = pf.pixelpostviewinterval2,
    si2 = pf.pixelsegmentinterval2,
    si3 = pf.pixelsegmentinterval3,
    si4 = pf.pixelsegmentinterval4,
    si5 = pf.pixelsegmentinterval5;

function data_copy() {

    var checked = pf.copy[0].checked,
        pci = pci1.value,
        pvi = pvi1.value,
        si = si1.value;

    pci2.value = checked ? pci : '';
    pvi2.value = checked ? pvi : '';
    si2.value = checked ? si : '';

    pci3.value = checked ? pci : '';
    pvi3.value = checked ? pvi : '';
    si3.value = checked ? si : '';

    pci4.value = checked ? pci : '';
    pvi4.value = checked ? pvi : '';
    si4.value = checked ? si : '';

    pci5.value = checked ? pci : '';
    pvi5.value = checked ? pvi : '';
    si5.value = checked ? si : '';

}
```